Compute even Clifford Group and Spin group in signature (2,2)
I would like to know how to calculate $\operatorname{CG^+}(2,2)$ and $\operatorname{Spin}(2,2)$. Here is the setting I am working with:
Let $V$ be the real 4-dimensional vector space $\operatorname{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $Q=\det$. Then $(V,Q)$ is a quadratic space of signature $(2,2)$. For me, $\operatorname{CG^+}(2,2)$ is the group $\operatorname{CG}(2,2)\cap\operatorname{Cl}(2,2)^+$, where $\operatorname{CG}(2,2)$ is the Clifford group and $\operatorname{Cl}(2,2)^+$ denotes the even Clifford algebra. $\operatorname{Spin}(2,2)$ is then the subgroup of those elements which have clifford norm $1$. I found out online that $\operatorname{Spin}(2,2)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. And I saw that $\operatorname{CG^+}(2,2)$ should be isomorphic to $H=\{(g,h)\in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})| \det g=\det h\}$. First question: is this correct?
Now I want to prove this. My idea was to use the fact that $\operatorname{CG^+}(2,2)$ and $\operatorname{Spin}(2,2)$ fit into certain exact sequences.
So I tried to show that the groups from above also fit into these sequences. If I find suitable homs from $\operatorname{CG^+}(2,2)$ to $H$ and from $\operatorname{Spin}(2,2)$ to $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, I would like to use the five lemmas to get the claim. Unfortunately, I have some problems with this. In particular, I have the following problems:
The groups $H$ and $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ act on $V$ by $v\mapsto gvh^{-1}$, where $(g,h)\in H$ resp. $\in\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.
I now have problems showing the exactness of the following sequences, both at $\operatorname{SO}(2,2)$. As well as constructing the maps between $\operatorname{CG^+}(2,2)$ and $H$ and from $\operatorname{Spin}(2,2)$ to $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. One problem is that I do not understand how to compute the Spinor norm of the map
$v\mapsto gvh^{-1}$.
I hope you understand my question. Thanks for your help. Btw, is there a way to use tikz directly in the editor instead of copying an image into the text?
Edit: I modified the question as suggested by @Nicholas Todoroff. By his comment it is also clear, that one just need to understand $\operatorname{Spin}(2,2).$

$Pin(2,2)$ is just the semidirect product $Pin(2,2)\cong Spin(2,2)\ltimes (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$, see here.

@DietrichBurde Not with the (nonstandard) definition provided, instead $Pin(2,2) = \mathbb R^\times\times Spin(2,2)$.

@Operander This is a nonstandard definition of $Pin$. It is better called the "even Clifford group" (and I also want to note that I prefer "Lipschitz group" over "Clifford group"). I think also when you say "generated by an even number of basis vectors" you mean "anisotropic/non-null vectors" instead; if you're truly only considering $e_ie_j, e_ie_je_ke_l, \dotsc$ then these group are very different from the usual Pin and Spin groups, and you really, really need a different name for it.
